# Apache POI poorly formatted text in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am still working on this job posting software for my company where I work as a school intern.
The software reads a job description from a .docx file and prints it into a container on a job posting website using Selenium.

This is my class for reading from .docx and writing into the container:

```
public class Description extends Driver {

    public static final String CRETURN = "\r";

    public static void ReadWriteDocx() {

        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Basics.docx");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);
            List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
            for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.size(); i++) {
                if (paragraphs.get(i).getParagraphText() != "") {
                    getDriver().findElement(By.id("AppendedJobDescription-editor-content")).sendKeys(CRETURN);
                }
                getDriver().findElement(By.id("AppendedJobDescription-editor-content")).sendKeys(paragraphs.get(i).getParagraphText());
            }
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**This is what the description looks like once it is pasted:**

IT Rollout (m/w/d) Du arbeitest gerne mit deinem Computer oder Laptop ? Dann bist du bei uns genau richtig ! Bewerbe dich jetzt als IT Supporter bei uns. Ihre Tätigkeiten. - PC´s auf-/abbauen - Transport der IT - Kundensupport Ihre Qualifikationen. - fließendes deutsch - Grundkenntnisse in der IT - Erfahrungen mit Hard- und Software - Grundkenntnisse in Microsoft Office

[**This is what it should look like.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEtLe.png)
The most important part is not, that the header is in bold or blue but that there are bulletpoints and carriage returns.

Is my approach entirely wrong?
If anyone could give me a suggestion I would be very grateful.

Comment: What is the type of the element WebDriver is writing the content into? Is it really an iframe as you stated? I would also try replacing "\r" with "\n".

Comment: It's probably highly unlikely that this is an issue with the element that you are pasting it into and more likely an issue with getting the text out of Word and properly formatting it. Create a new project where you just pull the text out of Word and write it to a text file, properly formatted. Once you have that sorted out then go back and add that code into your bigger project where it's inserted into a webpage. Breaking down bigger tasks into smaller ones to debug the issue will help you isolate the actual issue and save you a lot of time.

Comment: @kidney I will try replacing "\r" with "\n" thank you.
They changed some things about their website, before the containers id was "container-editor_**ifr**" so I just assumed it was an iframe but it seems I was wrong.

Comment: @JeffC That was indeed one of the first things that I tried, unfortunately it did not work as intended.

Comment: @kidney would there be a big difference if it was an iframe container?

Comment: I think there would. iframe contains an HTML document, so I'm not sure what effect `WebDriver.sendKeys` would have on it. But even if it did set the content, it would interpret it as HTML content, so newlines wouldn't really do anything. Unless it is some sort of rich text input component. But in that case, I would be surprised if it were an iframe.

Comment: Of course, @JeffC is right in that it is crucial to be sure the Word content is correctly read, i.e., the paragraphs are indeed distinguished.

Comment: @kidney so this is the HTML code for the container object.. I don't really know anything about HTML but I'm guessing this **not** a iframe
`<div id="AppendedJobDescription-editor-content" class="ecl-rich-text-editor-24yI1" data-placeholder="" contenteditable="true"></div>`

Comment: Ok, so it's a `div`, so no need to set HTML directly. And the text is really in read in paragraphs from the doc file and sending `\n` didn't help, right?

Comment: @kidney their site is currently down as soon as it's back up I'll find out.

Comment: @kidney I could kiss you right now, I swear I tried \n before but now it works. You're a hero. Post ur answer down below so I can close this post and give u credit btw.

Comment: @Arsaii, I'm happy it helped. I posted the answer below, thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `\n` for the newline in the target rich input instead of `\r`.